# Creating Static Table Header with dynamic table rows

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

I have checked so much links to get the information about static table header. Its working fine when the layout is static. But in my application only the header are known all the other rows are filled dynamically. So the alignment with header is missing.

I'm using a seperate table for header and seperate table for rows bcoz the header needs to float on the top and the rows are scrollable.

Is there any possibility to set the width dynamically to table columns.

Any Suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
NavaS.